# javascript timer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little javascript which I'm trying to use to make a timer. I got the code from another question on this site and it works ok on it's own, but since I'm making a few timers on this page I need to modify it a little and my modifications break it.

I'm not so brilliant with javascript and I can't see where I'm going wrong. All I've really done is add numerals (the id's of the products which have the timers) to the variable and function names. I've read it's ok to have numerals in variable and function names, so I'm at a loss.

The code I'm using (which isn't working) is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x1, secs1 = 61434; //declared globally
    x1 = setInterval(myFunc1, 1000);

    function myFunc1() {
        alert('yo');
        var minutes = Math.floor(secs1 / 60);
        var seconds = secs1 % 60;
        $('#timer_'1).html(minutes + ':' + seconds); //assuming there is a label with id 'timer'
        secs1--;
        if (secs1 == 0) {
            document.getElementById('timer').style.hidden = true;
            clearInterval(x1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('#timer_'1)` would cause a syntax error, did you mean `$('#timer_1')`?

Comment: please provide fiddle please.

Comment: please try this
$('#timer_1').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);

Comment: I think that was it Jain & go-oleg!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, and it's not obvious to me what you're trying to do. But one obvious problem is in these two lines:

```
$('#timer_'
    1).html(minutes + ':' + seconds); //assuming there is a label with id 'timer'
```

That will throw a syntax error, because `'#timer_'1` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @DJDavid98 I rolled back your edit because (1) it was an invalid edit and (2) it was incorrect. "Not valid syntax" is grammatically acceptable; there was no need to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here with the css selectors:

- `$('#timer_'1).html(minutes + ':' + seconds);` //add a + between timer_ and 1
- `document.getElementById('timer')`  //should be timer_1 too

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Drea/1zvLspxd/